# Terminology and Notation: "Sphere" in a Metric Sapce

Tags: metric-spaces, notation, definition

I see sphere used interchangeably with "ball" in the sense of "open ball", "closed ball", with notation like $B_r(x), B_r[x]$.

I also see sphere used to refer to the boundary of a closed ball, e.g. "unit sphere", but haven't seen a notation to go with it.

Is there an unambiguous term and notation which refers to the boundary of a closed ball and can't be mistaken for the ball itself.

Comment: $\partial B(x,r)$.

Comment: @copper.hat. Thanks for the notation. Any thoughts on terminology ?

Comment: No, sorry. It is peculiar that such an everyday sort of object (from a mathematical perspective) has no relevant vernacular.